# Install SCM software, accessible on the same PC all the time between Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04, windows-10, ntfs, visualsvn-server

My PC is dual boot, Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10.

What would be the best approach to install SCM(Source Code Management) software but being able to use it(access it) all the time, from Windows and Ubuntu?

Should I create separate partition and install there an SCM solution?

Should I use Git which is decentralized or Visual SVN server? 
Maybe Git/Cygwin on Windows, Git shell/Terminal on Ubuntu?

Should the partition be formatted with NTFS since Windows doesn't read Linux partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to have the repository locally? Why not use a web-based service like GitHub and then you only need to install the client tools on each of your OS environments and not worry about cross-platform filesystem support, which will be messy at best.

Comment: Yes, but I need to pay to keep my repo private on GitHub. I was preparing for a freelancer jobs, so not all code should be public, right?

Comment: @Vlad I would just pay for whatever SaaS service you need. If you store it locally, not you have to back it up, test restores, figure out the cross-plat issues, etc. I'd just buy a cloud service and call it a day.

Comment: Actually there is a way, with Ext2Fsd which is a Ext2 file system driver for Windows. You can view your code base both in ubuntu and in windows. But again, paying GitHub 7 dolars per month seems like a better bet.